# Error Order By Clause is invalid SQL Server

Tags: sql

Quisiera que me ayudaran con el error en el Order By, porque me marca el error de clausula

```
CREATE PROCEDURE SP_ExportExcelHistoryPRUEBA
-- ALL DATA DEFAULT(TODOS LOS DATOS)


AS BEGIN 

SET NOCOUNT ON 



DECLARE @TODAS VARCHAR(100)

-- CONSULT  ALL DATA
SET @TODAS = ( SELECT transportista.nombre, 
       registroembarque.transfer, 
       CASE 
         WHEN registroembarque.delivered = 1 THEN 'Delivered' 
         ELSE 
           CASE 
             WHEN registroembarque.nofactura IN (SELECT IM.[nofactura] 
                                                 FROM   imagenfactura IM) THEN 
             'Not Delivered' 
             ELSE 'Not Delivered / Missing Images' 
           END 
       END                                                          AS Delivered 
       , 
       Isnull(CONVERT(VARCHAR(12), registroembarque.fecharegistro, 101), 
       'InTransit') 
                                                                    AS Fecha, 
       registroembarque.nofactura                                   AS Factura, 
       registroembarque.pedimento, 
       registroembarque.ammex_usentry748, 
       chofer.nombre                                                AS Driver, 
       Isnull(contenedor.placascontenedor, '') 
       + Isnull(+ '/' + contenedornoeconomico.noeconomico, '')      AS 
       'Contenedor  (Placas/No.Eco)', 
       Isnull(RIGHT(CONVERT(VARCHAR(25), registroembarque.horamanifiestoslistos, 
                    100), 
              13), '')                                              AS 
       [Manifiestos Listos], 
       Isnull(RIGHT(CONVERT(VARCHAR(25), registroembarque.horacargayarda, 100), 
              13), '' 
       )                                                            AS 
       [Carga Yarda], 
       Isnull(RIGHT(CONVERT(VARCHAR(25), registroembarque.horainspeccion, 100), 
              13), '' 
       )                                                            AS 
       Inspeccion, 
       Isnull(resultadoverificacion.descripcion, N'')               AS 
       [Resultado Inspeccion], 
       Isnull(RIGHT(CONVERT(VARCHAR(25), 
              registroembarque.horamanifiestoslistos, 100), 13), '')AS 
       [Documentos Entregados], 
       Isnull(RIGHT(CONVERT(VARCHAR(25), 
                    registroembarque.horamoduclacionaduanamx, 100) 
              , 13), '')                                            AS [Mod MEX] 
       , 
       CASE 
         WHEN revisionmilitar = 0 THEN 'NO' 
         WHEN revisionmilitar IS NULL THEN '' 
         ELSE RIGHT(CONVERT(VARCHAR(25), 
              Isnull(registroembarque.horamoduclacionaduanamx, ''), 
              100), 13) 
              + '/' 
              + RIGHT(CONVERT(VARCHAR(25), 
              Isnull(registroembarque.horarevisionmilitarsalida, ''), 100), 13) 
       END                                                          AS 
       [Rev Militar MEX (Entrada/Salida)], 
       CASE 
         WHEN reconocimientous = 0 THEN 'NO' 
         WHEN reconocimientous IS NULL THEN '' 
         ELSE RIGHT(CONVERT(VARCHAR(25), 
              Isnull(registroembarque.reconocimientousentrada, ''), 
              100), 13) 
              + '/' 
              + RIGHT(CONVERT(VARCHAR(25), 
              Isnull(registroembarque.reconocimientoussalida, ''), 100), 13) 
       END                                                          AS 
       [ReconocimientoUS (Entrada/Salida)], 
       Isnull(Substring(registroembarque.notas, 0, 10), '')         AS 
       Observaciones, 
       Isnull (registroembarque.notas, '')                          AS 
       NotasCompletas, 
       Isnull(RIGHT(CONVERT(VARCHAR(25), 
                    registroembarque.horamodulacionaduanaus, 100), 
              13), '')                                              AS 
       HoraModulacionAduanaUS, 
       CASE 
         WHEN reconocimiento = 0 THEN 'NO' 
         WHEN reconocimiento IS NULL THEN '' 
         ELSE RIGHT(CONVERT(VARCHAR(25), 
              Isnull(registroembarque.horareconocimientoentrada, '' 
              ), 100), 13) 
              + '/' 
              + RIGHT(CONVERT(VARCHAR(25), 
              Isnull(registroembarque.horareconocimientosalida, ''), 100), 13) 
       END                                                          AS 
       [Reconocimiento (Entrada/Salida)], 
       resultadoverificacion.descripcion, 
       Isnull(RIGHT(CONVERT(VARCHAR(25), 
                    registroembarque.aar_fechahoracaptura, 100), 
              13), '') 
       [DocsRecvFromDO], 
       Isnull(RIGHT(CONVERT(VARCHAR(25), registroembarque.ammex_docsready, 108), 
              13), 
       '')                                                          AS 
       [AMMEXDocsReady], 
       Isnull(registroembarque.ammex_docstodriver, '')              AS 
       AMMEX_DocsToDriver, 
       Isnull(RIGHT(CONVERT(VARCHAR(25), 
                    registroembarque.horamoduclacionaduanamx, 100) 
              , 13), '')                                            [SATArrival] 
       , 
       Isnull(CASE 
                WHEN CONVERT(DATE, registroembarque.ammex_cbparrival) = 
                     '1900-01-01' 
              THEN '' 
                ELSE CONVERT(CHAR(10), registroembarque.ammex_cbparrival, 108) 
              END, '')                                              AS 
       [CBPArrival], 
       Isnull(CASE 
                WHEN CONVERT(DATE, registroembarque.ammex_cbprelease) = 
                     '1900-01-01' 
              THEN '' 
                ELSE CONVERT(CHAR(10), registroembarque.ammex_cbprelease, 108) 
              END, '')                                              AS 
       [CBPRelease] ,

       /*NEW DATA*/
       Obs.descripcion AS Observations,
       (SELECT u.descripcion + ',' 
        FROM   embarque_unloading eu 
               INNER JOIN unloading u 
                       ON u.idunloading = eu.idunloading 
        WHERE  eu.nofactura = RegistroEmbarque.nofactura 
        FOR xml path(''))                   AS Unloadings, 
       (SELECT u.descripcion + ',' 
        FROM   embarque_delay eu 
               INNER JOIN delays u 
                       ON u.iddelay = eu.iddelay 
        WHERE  eu.nofactura = RegistroEmbarque.NoFactura 
        FOR xml path(''))                   AS Delays, 
       incidencia 
       /*END NEW DATA*/

FROM   RegistroEmbarque 
       INNER JOIN chofer 
               ON registroembarque.cheferid = chofer.cheferid 
       INNER JOIN contenedor 
               ON registroembarque.contenedorid = contenedor.contenedorid 
       INNER JOIN contenedornoeconomico 
               ON registroembarque.contenedornoeconomicoid = 
                  contenedornoeconomico .contenedornoeconomicoid 
       INNER JOIN transportista 
               ON registroembarque.transportistaid = 
                  transportista.transportistaid 
       LEFT OUTER JOIN resultadoverificacion 
               ON registroembarque.resultadoverificacionid = 
                       resultadoverificacion.resultadoverificacionid 
        -- NEW DATA
        LEFT OUTER JOIN Observaciones Obs 
               ON Obs.idobservacion = RegistroEmbarque.AMMEX_IdObservation
               -- END NEW DATA
WHERE  registroembarque.estado = 2 
ORDER  BY NoFactura ASC )

END 
GO
-- END ALL DATA
```

Comment: ¿Es esto una vista, cuál es la consulta completa?

Comment: @james_bond Una disculpa ahí esta completo , es un stored procedure, lo hice de esa manera porque tengo varias consultas, es decir es una consulta dinámica dentro de un stored procedure.

Comment: Daniel, prueba haciendo `ORDER  BY registroembarque.nofactura ASC`. Saludos.

Comment: De la forma como lo veo tenes como opción usar una tabla temporal e insertar el resultado de la consulta  para luego consultar la tabla ya con los datos ordenados y operar sobre los resultados.

Comment: @PatricioMoracho me sale el mismo error, también probé utilizando el `SELECT TOP`

Answer (score 0):

El problema que tienes se puede resumir conceptualmente en el siguiente ejemplo

```
declare @name varchar(255)

select @name = (select  name
            from systypes
            order by name
        )
```

El error:

> The ORDER BY clause is invalid in views, inline functions, derived
>   tables, subqueries, and common table expressions, unless TOP, OFFSET
>   or FOR XML is also specified.

#### ¿Que significa?

No puedes usar una clausula `ORDER` en una subconsulta, tan simple como eso. Sin embargo si podrías hacer lo siguiente:

```
declare @name varchar(255)

select @name = name
    from systypes
    order by name
```

Al sacar los paréntesis, ya no tienes una subconsulta sino que tienes una única consulta. De todas formas en operaciones con variables, el `ORDER BY` solo tiene sentido si estamos buscando quedarnos con el último de los registros, una operación de selección a una variable normalmente debiera traernos un solo registro, por que una variable no puede alojar más de uno (a menos que concatenemos pero no es este el caso). Otro tema que no entiendo muy bien es que buscas al devolver una subconsulta con varias columnas y la intentas asignar a una única variable. Te sugiero que en todo caso hagas algo como esto:

```
SELECT @TransportistaNombre = transportista.nombre, 
       @RegistroembarqueTransfer = registroembarque.transfer, 
       ...
       ORDER  BY NoFactura ASC
```

O sea cada columna con su respectiva variable, si solo necesitamos un dato, solo dejamos esa columna. La consulta ahora sí, sin paréntesis, y usamos directamente el `SELECT` y no el `SET` para la asignación. El `ORDER BY` solo si la consulta nos devuelve más de un registro y queremos asignar finalmente el más nuevo por `NoFactura`.

Nota: No debiéramos abusar de esta técnica para obtener el último de los registros, imagina una consulta de millones de filas que hacemos solo para obtener la última, hay formas más óptimas de resolverlo desde la lógica `SQL`.

Comment: muchas gracias, lo que pasa es que estoy haciendo una consulta dinámica dentro de un Stored Procedure, lo cual mejor use una consulta por cada stored procedure, así pude resolver mi problema.

Answer (score 0):

De acuerdo con la respuesta anterior, es correcto que no se puede utilizar order by en vistas, funciones, subconsultar, etc.

Veo que deseas retornar el resultado de una consulta, para ello lo puedes hacer con una vista o función, y utilizar el order by donde es llamada.

```
CREATE FUNCTION obtenerdatos (@storeid int)  
RETURNS TABLE  
AS  
RETURN   
(  
    SELECT P.ProductID, P.Name
    FROM Production.Product AS P  
    WHERE C.StoreID = @storeid  
);
```

y luego puedes hacer un:

```
select * from obtenerdatos(25)
```

O con una vista.

Answer (score 0):

Muchas Gracias a todos, obtuve una manera diferente de hacerlo, espero les sirva.

```
  Create Procedure Sp_Ejemplo

@Busqueda as varchar(20)
AS BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON

IF(@Busqueda = 'Todas')
BEGIN 
SELECT SELECT transportista.nombre, 
       registroembarque.transfer, 
       CASE .......

END 


IF(@Busqueda = 'MESES')
BEGIN 
SELECT SELECT transportista.nombre, 
       registroembarque.transfer, 
       CASE .......

END 

END GO
```